# Error equation on multiple line

Tags: equations, align, center

I'm trying to use the equation tag on the following portion of formula:
[image]

I did it as well:

```
\begin{equation}
\centerline{$
\min _{w, b, \xi_{i}} \frac{\|w\|^{2}}{2}+C \sum_{i=1}^{n} \xi_{i}
$} 

subject to:

\centerline{$
\begin{aligned}
y_{i}\left(w^{T} \phi\left(x_{i}\right)+b\right) \geq 1-\xi_{i} & & \text { for all } i=1, \ldots, n \\
\xi_{i} \geq 0 & & \text { for all } i=1, \ldots, n
\end{aligned}$}
\end{equation}
```

but when I run it I get the following error:

> 1 - Missing $ inserted.

> 2 - Display math should end with $$.

> 3 - Bad math environment delimiter.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.

Comment: `\centerline shouldn't really be used in latex and certainly not in or around equations.  you can also not have blank lines in equations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this?:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
\min _{w, b, \xi_{i}} \frac{\|w\|^{2}}{2}+C \sum_{i=1}^{n} \xi_{i}
\shortintertext{subject to:}
\begin{aligned}
y_{i}\left(w^{T} \phi\left(x_{i}\right)+b\right) \geq 1-\xi_{i} & & \text { for all } i=1, \ldots, n \\
\xi_{i} \geq 0 & & \text { for all } i=1, \ldots, n
\end{aligned}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Edit:**
As Sebastiano suggest in a comment this optimization problems should be written with `optidef` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{optidef}
\begin{document}
\begin{mini}
{w, b, \xi_{i}}{\frac{\|w\|^{2}}{2}+C \sum_{i=1}^{n} \xi_{i}}{}{}
\addConstraint{y_{i}\left(w^{T} \phi\left(x_{i}\right)+b\right)}{\geq 1-\xi_{i}\quad}{\text {for all } i=1, \ldots, n}
\addConstraint{\xi_{i}}{\geq 0}{\text {for all } i=1, \ldots, n}
\end{mini}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The package has many environments and many alternatives to display this optimization problem. It also has some aligning points, that I have used in the example

Comment: +1 surely. I think that the optidef package It seems Better.

Comment: I will see `optidef` package, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Very very good. It Is very nice. I had upvoted Yesterday.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about `optidef` package